# How to remove div elements from the DOM tree one by one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is [my example](http://codepen.io/MarinaShumeiko/pen/aBYXQG).

By clicking the add button, I add a user card. "Clear button" removes all cards. How to remove cards one by one clicking on the "close" icon in each card?

HTML file

```
<div class="header">
  <button id="clear" class="button clear">Clear</button>
  <button id="button" class="button add">Add user</button>
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

JS file

```
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
var index = 0;
$.ajax({
  url: root + '/posts/1/comments',
  method: 'GET'
}).then(function(data) {
  $("#button").click(function() {
  var notificationMessage = "Oops, there are no more user cards to display";
  if (index >= data.length ) {
    return alert(notificationMessage);
  }
  $("#content").append('<div id="card"><div class="title"><div class="image"></div><div id="name">'
    + data[index].name + '</div><span id="close"></span></div><div id="description">'
    + data[index].body + '<a href="mailto:" id="email">'
    + data[index].email + '</a></div></div>'
  );
  index++;
  // remove all cards from a list and return index equally [0], to be able add user card again.
  $("#clear").click(function() {
    $("#card").remove();
    index = 0;
  });
});
});

//How to remove card by clicking on the close button?
```

Comment: don't use id repeatedly. try to use class

Comment: Thanks guys a LOT! I'm very beginner in  jquery. Just started to play with it one month ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you try to use class in `card` element?
because `id` selector only get first matching element

```
$.ajax({
    url: root + '/posts/1/comments',
    method: 'GET'
  }).then(function(data) {        
    $("#button").click(
      function() {
        var notificationMassage = "Oops, there are no more user cards to display";

        if (index >= data.length ) {
          return alert(notificationMassage);
        }

        $("#content").append('<div class="card"><div class="title"><div class="image"></div><div class="name">'
              + data[index].name + '</div><span class="close"></span></div><div class="description">' 
              + data[index].body + '<a href="mailto:" id="email">'
              + data[index].email + '</a></div></div>'
         );
        index++;

        // remove all cards from a list and return index equally [0], to be able add user card again.
        $("#clear").click(function() {
          $("#content").html('');
          index = 0;
        }); 
    });
```

to remove one by one add this code

```
        // remove one cards from a list.
        $("#content").on("click", ".close", function() {
          $(this).closest('div.card').remove();
        });
```

Comment: The close handler needs to be delegated or it will not work on newly added items

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ids should be unique. I recommend changing yours into classes.

```
$("#content").append('<div class="card"><div class="title"><div class="image"></div><div class="name">'
          + data[index].name + '</div><span class="close"></span></div><div id="description">' 
          + data[index].body + '<a href="mailto:" id="email">'
          + data[index].email + '</a></div></div>'
     );
```

Now that we have all close icons with class `close`, we can add the following listener for all `.close` buttons to remove only the card which contains them.

```
$(document).on('click', '.close', function(){
    $(this).closest('.card').remove(); // remove only closest '.card'
});
```

Comment: `$('.close').on('click', func() {});` will not work as items are added dynamically!

Comment: No, Saumya Rastogi is correct. You are attaching individual handlers to all matching existing items only. You need to make it the delegated version of `on`

Comment: You guys are right, I got confused for a second. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to implement what you want:

```
$("body").on("click", ".close", function(e) {
  $(this).closest('.card').remove();
});
```

> **Note:** Remember that use only single ID on a single page, instead use classes to make it work

See this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/saumya04/pen/QGrZZj?editors=1111)

```
// jQuery on() method description
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
```

> See more about jQuery's [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That will never work as you have an ID selector for close.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to change id to to class.

And here is solution:

codepen.io/ivanchuda/pen/xRjyJp

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would change the ID on the divs to class instead since you are generating multiple cards. IDs should be unique. Then I would change the code to add one more line to your close-span:

```
<span class="close" onclick="$(this).parent().parent().remove()"></span>
```

Comment: I strongly recommend not using inline handlers in combination with jQuery. It bloats the HTML and loses many features jQuery events add. Use a jQuery delegated event handler instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this**

**[`See the updated codeopen`](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RoyeBE)**

Change the `id` to `class` .And match with `parent() of parent()` 
[**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) more important

```
$(document).on("click",".close",function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove()

        });
```

Comment: using `closest()` is generally shorter and is more robust to DOM changes than .parent().parent() etc.

Answer (score 0):

The short and not elegant answer is:

```
$("#content").on("click", "span[id=close]", function() {
    $(this).closest("div[id=card]").remove();
});
```

This should work, but you need to do a better job than this. Your HTML is invalid, since `id` is expected to be unique and you use the very same `id` for different items. You could use `class`es instead, or make sure that the identifier is unique. Note that your SEO will instantly improve if you make your HTML valid. If you use `class`es instead of not-unique `id`s, then the script above will change to this one:

```
//content is unique, therefore it can remain an id
$("#content").on("click", "span.close", function() {
    $(this).closest("div.card").remove();
});
```